# Java Object[] cast to long[][] performance issuse?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, casting

Hello I am curious are there any serious performance consequences from performing the following type of cast? Especially when it's performance millions of times thanks

```
Object [] car = new Object[1];

car[0] = new Long[2][2];

long[][] values = (long[][]) car[0];
```

Comment: Its not good to do, performance isn't much issue here

Comment: -1 for not just testing this and profiling. This *could* depend on the JDK you're using, and the answers provided here will only be theoretical.

Comment: Are you trying to cast a Long[][] (Object array) to a long[][] (primitive array) or is that a typo?

Answer (score 3):

Casting really isn't much of a performance issue. It's just meta data for the compiler to know how to treat the object. Of course, if it tries to use a object as the wrong type, you'll get a `ClassCastException`, which can cause performance issues.

Comment: +1 This seems to be the only answer actually *answering* the question and not nit-picking about it :/

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the performance issue is that that case makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. Why would you ever do that?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written will cause a class cast exception. Throwing millions of class cast exceptions will probably be slow. It is also unlikely to be the intended logic.

Answer (score 0):

The impact of a cast depends on your jvm and the code in which it is used. The cast operation should be highly optimized in modern jvms since it is used quite often for generic classes so its overhead should be quite low.

If your code has to be fast you should profile it to find bottlenecks, this will also answer if the cast is a problem in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the following cast. I suggest you make the array a long[][] from the start and you won't need to convert the array type.

```
// these won't work as these are different types of references. 
long[] longs = (long[]) new Long[0];
long[][] longs = (long[][]) new Long[0][];
```

The only way to convert them is to iterate over them.

```
Long[][] longs = ...
long[][] longs2 = new long[longs.length][];
for(int i=0;i<longs.length;i++) {
  longs2[i] = new long[longs[i].length];
  for(int j=0;j<longs[i].length;j++) longs2[i][j] = longs[i][j];
}
```

The main performance cost is in creating the Long[][] in the first place as you have to create many objects whereas with long[][] you have only the arrays making the structure much more efficient for memory and cpu.

Answer (score 0):

if hotspot can prove that Object is actually long[][] the cost is none, otherwise it costs a check + branch prediction, which usually is successful and it is an extra (only one) cpu cycle.

The casting is *not* exactly free like one of the answer suggests and it's not only metadata.